# Check if a query exists using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a procedure in VBA which runs a report based on what user select on a dropdown (Report Name and grouping criteria) in a form. Also, I have a button which that user selection can be transferred to Excel.
The part of the procedure where I want to test if the query exist is below:

```
If Not IsNull(Me.cmbGroup.Value) Or Me.cmbGroup.Value = "" Then

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryCrossTotGroup WHERE [Group]='" & Me.cmbGroup.Value & "'"
    'MsgBox strSQL

    With MyDatabase
        .QueryDefs.Delete ("tmpOutQry")
        Set MyQueryDef = .CreateQueryDef("tmpOutQry", strSQL)
    End With

    'Step 3: Open the query
    Set MyRecordset = MyDatabase.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    'Step 4: Clear previous contents
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .Workbooks.Add
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    'Step 5: Copy the recordset to Excel
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset

    'Step 6: Add column heading names to the spreadsheet
        For i = 1 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count
            xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next i
        xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End If
```

I want to test if query "tmpOutQry" exist in order to delete it. Have someone that line of code?

Comment: Did you do a simple google search for ["access vba test if query exists"](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+vba+test+if+query+exists&oq=access+vba+to+test+if+query+e&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.8457j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? If so, you would have gotten [this answer](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/765384-determine-if-query-x-exists) as a first result.

Comment: I did that search and got the current page as the first answer.  I don't think you can say that just because you got a particular search response everyone will get the same.   just say'n

Answer (score 4):

You don't use the temp query, so you can reduce your first steps to:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryCrossTotGroup WHERE [Group]='" & Me.cmbGroup.Value & "'"
'MsgBox strSQL

'Step 3: Open the query
Set MyRecordset = MyDatabase.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: I got it to work! Post this for others: With MyDatabase
    For Each MyQueryDef In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
     If MyQueryDef.Name = "tmpOutQry" Then
     
       .QueryDefs.Delete ("tmpOutQry")
       Exit For
       End If
       Next

        Set MyQueryDef = .CreateQueryDef("tmpOutQry", strSQL)
    End With

Comment: Glad you got it working, but..... you create `MyQueryDef`, then at the point that you should use it you use `Set MyRecordset = MyDatabase.OpenRecordset(strSQL)` to query the database instead.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this code and worked:

```
With MyDatabase
For Each MyQueryDef In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
 If MyQueryDef.Name = "tmpOutQry" Then

   .QueryDefs.Delete ("tmpOutQry")
   Exit For
   End If
   Next

    Set MyQueryDef = .CreateQueryDef("tmpOutQry", strSQL)
End With
```

Comment: The tmpOutQry was needed to hold the selected report data and export it into Excel. Every time when a new report was selected I needed to check for old temporary query, delete it and make a new one to take the new data and export to excel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use for this; I don't like the idea of iterating through every QueryDef in a database, and sometimes with VBA you have to accept that not every collection or type has the methods that will enable you to test it "conventionally."

```
On Error Resume Next
    If CurrentDb.QueryDefs("queryDefName").Name = "queryDefName" Then
    'It exists; do something

    ElseIf Err.Number = 3265 Then
        Err.Clear
        'it doesn't exist; do something else
        
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Using a precise error number (3265 is "item not in collection") is as close as you can get, AND you don't needlessly iterate over what in some Access applications can be a large collection.